# Symfony2, Sonata : Customize title of collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, sonata

I've been able to translate most of the titles but i still have some non-friendly titles on collections (Table of relation)

[image: Title]

> Aire\AppBundle\Entity\ProjectSupported:000000002d1a645a000000015441bb1f

How could i custom them?

At best it could be the name of the related object (**$investor->getName()** and **$project->getName()** for exemple), at worst just a string.

In that case i'm using en entity with 2 relations

```
/**
 * Owning Side
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Investor", inversedBy="supportedProject")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="investor_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $investor;

/**
 * Owning Side
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="supportedProject")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $project;
```

Any hints or solutions?

Comment: The __toString method ?

Comment: That was indeed the solution, I forget to add __toString method in that entity ... I let you set it as an answer if you wish to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonata is using the `__toString` method for text representation of objects.